# python iterator: why does this work?

Tags: python

I have an object which defines the iterator interface and also contains a built in file reader (and uses its iterator interface as follows)

```
class MyIter(object):
    def __init__(path):
        self.file = open(path, "r")

    def next(self):
        line = self.file.next()
        return line

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

I call it as:

```
r = MyIter("path_to_file")
for item in r:
    print item
```

This prints the whole file upto the last line. My question is that I never had to add any check for EOF or check the length of the returned line to specify some end condition. Why does this work?

Comment: It works because it's just a proxy over a file iterator: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next

Comment: `self.file.next()` raises `StopIteration` when there is no more to iterate. That signals the iteration to end.

Comment: Note that you could just make the `__iter__` implementation `return self.file`.

Comment: Ah yes, but my example was very minimal. I do parse the line in the file to return a tuple, but I did not mention it as it would be just a distraction to my main question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your next implementation calls [`file.next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) which has its own EOF check. "This method returns the next input line, or raises StopIteration when EOF is hit when the file is open for reading"

Answer (score 5):

The [`next()`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/file/next.html) method returns the next input line, or raises `StopIteration` when EOF is hit. So it automatically handles the EOF limitations.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Python expert but should you be referencing "item" in the for?

```
for item in r:
    print "item ==> ", item
```

But, yes, the next() method is raising the StopIteration for you.

Comment: Yup, exceptions will be passed up the stack and will generally behave the same whether you called `next` yourself or called some code that called `next`. Imho this is a fundamental flaw in the design of the exception system. If you call some code in another module and that code leaks an exception, then all you will see is that your for-loop terminates. You will spend ages chasing this bug.

Comment: That's an interesting insight. However, the stack trace should help with the debugging?